# Android: difference between BitmapFactory.decodeResource() and BitmapFactory.decodeFile() result?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I'm noticing a crash (in an external native library that does some image processing) when I pass it the pixel data returned from [bitmap.getPixels()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

If I package the image in the app, in the drawables folder and load the Bitmap with

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource()
```

then grab the pixel data with

```
bitmap.getPixels()
```

there's no crash, and everything works as expected. However, if I load the same image from the file system with

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile()
```

then grab the pixels with

```
bitmap.getPixels()
```

and hand that off, the native lib crashes.

Is there a difference between the way these two calls process the image into a Bitmap?

Comment: Can you get any logs from the native library?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's not my code.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Android sources There is one interesting diffrence: The `decodeFile` method may call a different native bitmap decoder if the passed file is an asset, while the `decodeResource` will never do this.

```
if (is instanceof AssetManager.AssetInputStream) {
            bm = nativeDecodeAsset(((AssetManager.AssetInputStream) is).getAssetInt(),
                    outPadding, opts);
```

However, the crash is most likely a bug in your native code. Messing up the stackframe with bad pointers and/or buffer overruns typically results in weird crashes like this. Try to check all your native code that runs before the crash and see if you can spot any memory issues like that.

Comment: I just ran a test on the two different methods. Loading from resources produces a Bitmap with twice the width and height of the original image, while loading from a file does no scaling. I'm not sure why scaling the image keeps the native code from crashing.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, I scaled the Bitmap from the file using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(), doubling the size, and the crash went away. Not sure what's going on under the hood, but that solves my issue. FYI, the JPEG is from Facebook. My guess is there's some anomaly that is corrected when the image is scaled.